# Cant get the text input to align vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to align the text input field to align vertically 
I have two dividers inside the form tag that are have position: relative; and float:left; 
and they dont align vertically...

I really cant figure out how to fix it. I really need the dividers because i run js that changes certain properties and i use the dividers to change the look of the input element

here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/CMFQJ/

anybody has any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best working code that can be done by me for you here http://jsfiddle.net/CMFQJ/5/

Comment: thats much better then what i have. But i want the inputs to be right next to each other and not to be in the middle. Just very small in the top left corner

Comment: try the link given before your comment

Comment: I started commenting before the link in the comments existed